# PDO Prepared Statements - Viewing Query Results

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

So I've consolidated together some code trying to make a prepared PDO statement in php/mysql.

Everything is running in the sense that the page isn't bugging out, but I can't seem to pull the results of the query to 'echo' in the html and I don't know what I'm missing.

Here's my code before the `<head>`:

```
try {  
    # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL  
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname_db;dbname=$database_db", $username_db, $password_db);  
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    // writ the query
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?');  
    $stmt -> execute(array($rid));
    $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}  
// Error message for pdo
catch(PDOException $e) {  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
```

Then down in the html of the page, I'm trying to view the results like this:

```
<body>
<p>Hello</p>
<p><?php echo $results['field1']; echo ', row count: '.$row_count;?></p>
</body>
```

The $row_count is coming in correctly as 1, but I'm trying to call the value in 'field1', but nothing is coming up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fetchall docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Returns multiple rows back in an array: `array(row_1, row_2)`.

The rows them self are array too.

So you try to access a row that does not exists. So you should use fetch or a foreach

Fetch:

```
$results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Foreach:

```
foreach($results as $result){ 
  echo $result['field_1'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`PDO::fetchAll` returns an array of results i.e. an array of associative arrays. You might want to use `PDO::fetch` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:-

```
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to

```
$results = $stmt->fetch();
```